# Is it a good practice to forbid IP access to port 80?

Tags: server, ip, ubuntu, nginx

I see some sites have blocked there port 80 (or 443) to be accessed by IP.
When you access by IP, an Nginx forbidden page shows up (with there OS version).
My question is does it affect any side of security of that sever and web application running on it in a positive way?
If it depends on OS please provided for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

> I see some sites have blocked there port 80 (or 443) to be accessed by IP.

My guess is that you mean that access to `http://hostname` works while `http://ip-adress/` does not work. At the TCP level the host is still accessed by IP address but the HTTP request looks different because the name given in the URL is contained in the HTTP request, e.g.

```
 GET /some-page HTTP/1.1
 Host: hostname
```

The main reason for having the hostname inside the HTTP request is that you often have multiple virtual servers with different hostnames on the same IP address. These have different configurations and the server needs to be able to distinguish which configuration should be used. If you give a hostname which does not have any special configuration then some default configuration is used and often this just displays an error page (what else should it do?).

And this exactly is what happens when you give an IP address instead of the hostname. Since there is no special configuration for `Host: IP address` the default configuration showing the error will be used.

Apart from that it makes sense to properly check the hostname even if their is only a single site on this IP address, because accepting an arbitrary hostname  can lead to [DNS rebinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding) and similar attacks.

Comment: Besides what was said by Steffen, - having the same content accessible by 2 different paths (by IP and by hostname) will lower SEO score because of duplicate content.

Comment: @Alex right. Some sites even redirect http://example.com to www.example.com

Comment: +1.  The only "security risk" that may be there is that your default page exposes data such as "You're running Nginx [VERSION] on CentOS [VERSION]".

Comment: How it's related to original question ? The same information can be reviled even if site is accessible only by hostname. It is very questionable that you think it is "security risk". There're a bunch of methods to fingerprint OS and particular service without this information at all.